# Jogl: How to make a transparent background on com.jogamp.opengl.swt.GLCanvas?

Tags: opengl, swt, transparent, jogl, blend

I searched & read multiple forums about openGL transparency and I found this piece of code

```
gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
gl.glAlphaFunc(GL2.GL_GREATER, 0.1f);
gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Some people wrote this code inside the `init` method and got result. I really don't know anymore about Blending, but I added this code and nothing happened!

Is there any mistake or misunderstanding here!? How can I do that?

I'm using `jogl 2.0` by the way.

Comment: What is it exactly what you try to do? Do you want your OpenGL window to be translucent? If so, that you also need a window pixelformat / visual / fbconfig with an alpha channel and a alpha mask; since you rely on Jogl creating the window, it depends on if Jogl does support this at all.

Comment: @datenwolf I don't want make a transparent `SHELL`, I want to have a transparent `GLCanvas`. Think, we have two `GLCanvas`es on a shell and one of them is top of other, Now how we can transparent the top GLCanvas.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can make a transparent `GLJPanel`, via refining it's `GLCapabilities`:

```
/** Creates an instance of a transparent GLJPanel. **/
public static final GLJPanel createTransparentPanel() {
    /* Instantiate a new set of GLCapabilities based upon the System's default parameters. */
    final GLCapabilities lGLCapabilities = new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.getDefault());
    /* Define that we don't wish for the background to be opaque. */
    lGLCapabilities.setBackgroundOpaque(false);
    /* Create a new GLJPanel based on these capabilities. */
    final GLJPanel lGLJPanel = new GLJPanel(lGLCapabilities);
    /* Disable opacity for the panel. */
    lGLJPanel.setOpaque(false);
    /* Return the panel. */
    return lGLJPanel;
}
```

This can then be added to a transparent `JFrame`. You can enable transparency for your JFrame by calling:

```
.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

Comment: Your answer is off topic as he uses com.jogamp.opengl.swt.GLCanvas instead of GLJPanel.

Comment: I thought that this was a suitable workaround for such an old question.